# How to leave only rows that meet a specific condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, data-management

I have a data frame that contains around 700 cases with 1800 examinations. Some cases underwent several different modalities. I want to leave only one examination result based on the specific condition of the modality.

Here is a dummy data frame:

```
df <- data.frame (ID = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "4", "4", "5", "5"),
                  c1 = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C"),
                  x1 = c(5, 4, 5, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5),
                  x2 = c(4, 3, 7, 9, 1, 2, 4, 7, 5, 0))
```

There are five cases with 10 exams. [c1] is the exam modality (condition), and the results are x1 and x2.

I want to leave only one row based on the following condition:

> C > B > A

I want to leave the row with C first; if not, leave the row with B; If C and B are absent, leave the row with A.

Desired output:

```
output <- data.frame (ID = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
                      c1 = c("C", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
                      x1 = c(5, 1, 3, 2, 5),
                      x2 = c(7, 1, 2, 7, 0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `arrange` the data based on required correct order and for each `ID` select it's 1st row.

```
library(dplyr)

req_order <- c('C', 'B', 'A')

df %>%
  arrange(ID, match(c1, req_order)) %>%
  distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE)

#  ID    c1       x1    x2
#  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 1     C         5     7
#2 2     C         1     1
#3 3     A         3     2
#4 4     B         2     7
#5 5     C         5     0
```

In base R, this can be written as :

```
df1 <- df[order(match(df$c1, req_order)), ]
df1[!duplicated(df1$ID), ]
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! I like it as you applied dplyr.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

```
df.srt <- df[order(df$c1, decreasing=TRUE), ]
df.spl <- split(df.srt, df.srt$ID)
first <- lapply(df.spl, head, n=1)
result <- do.call(rbind, first)
result
#   ID c1 x1 x2
# 1  1  C  5  7
# 2  2  C  1  1
# 3  3  A  3  2
# 4  4  B  2  7
# 5  5  C  5  0
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @dcarlson. However, I have to say that order(, decreasing=TRUE) won't work in my real data. I can change the coding and apply your solution, but another answer without changing the coding will be appreciated.

Comment: Hard to guess without knowing what your coding is, but converting to a factor would let you specify the ordering. For example, `c1fact <- factor(df$c1, c("B", "A", "C"))` would change the order to B > A > C.

Comment: That's a really smart tip. Thank you very much. That makes sense!